# Как исправить проблему с перескакиванием номера страницы при перелистывании

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть файл Json из него загружаем данные и формируем объекты на странице.
Если пролистывать при помощи стрелок перескакивают страницы.
Помогите понять в чем дело.

```js
let block = document.querySelector('#block');
let pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination__list');
let prevPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_prev');
let nextPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_next');

let notesOnPage = 4;
let active;

async function getJson() {
  const fileJson = 'json/product.json';
  let response = await fetch(fileJson, {
    method: "GET"
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    let result = await response.json();
    loadProducts(result);
    alert("Данные загружены");
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    alert("ошибка")
  }
}

function loadProducts(data) {

  const proData = data.products;

  let countOfItems = Math.ceil(proData.length / notesOnPage);

  let paginationItem = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= countOfItems; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('pagination__item');
    pagination.appendChild(li);
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = i;
    li.appendChild(span);
    paginationItem.push(span);
  }


  showPage(paginationItem[0]);


  for (let item of paginationItem) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      showPage(this);
    });
  }

  function showPage(item) {

    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove('_active')
    }
    active = item;
    item.classList.add('_active');

    let pageNum = +item.innerHTML;

    let start = (pageNum - 1) * notesOnPage;
    let end = start + notesOnPage;
    let notes = proData.slice(start, end);

    block.innerHTML = '';

    for (let item of notes) {
      const productTitle = item.title;
      const productImage = item.img;
      block.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
        `<div class="block__item">
                    <h2 class="block__title">${productTitle}</h2>
                    <img class="block__img" src="img/icons/${productImage}" alt="">
                    </div>`
      );
      hideOverPages();
    }

    prevPage.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (active.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
        showPage(active.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span'));
      }
    });
    nextPage.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (active.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
        showPage(active.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('span'));
      }
    });

    function hideOverPages() {
      let items = [...pagination.children];
      if (items.length > 5) {
        items.forEach(function(item) {
          item.classList.add('_hide')
        });
        items[0].classList.remove('_hide');
        if (active.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
          active.parentElement.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('_hide');
        }
        active.parentElement.classList.remove('_hide');
        if (active.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
          active.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('_hide');
        }
        items[items.length - 1].classList.remove('_hide');
      }
    }
  }
}

getJson();
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.block__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  padding: 5px;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__arrow_next {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_next:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(-10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 20px;
}

.pagination__item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__item span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__item span._active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__item._hide {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.pagination__item._hide:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "• • •";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.pagination__item._hide+._hide {
  display: none;
}

.pagination__link {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="block"></div>

<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_prev"></div>
  <ul class="pagination__list">
  </ul>
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_next"></div>
</div>
```

```
{
```

"products": [
{
"title": "Pagination 1",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 2",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 3",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 4",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 5",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 6",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 7",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 8",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 9",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 10",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 11",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 12",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 13",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 14",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 15",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 16",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 17",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 18",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 19",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 20",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 21",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 22",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 23",
"img": "loading.gif"
},
{
"title": "Pagination 24",
"img": "loading.gif"
}
]
}

Comment: Не знаю как добавить файл.

Comment: Что такое "перескакивают страницы"? Помогите понять в чем дело.

Comment: добавил изображение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно, все скачет. И чем дальше, тем больше будет скакать.

Сколько обработчиков события `click` Вы добавляете к кнопкам `prevPage` и `nextPage`?

---

Вынесите код

```
prevPage.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
nextPage.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
```

из функции `showPage`.

Comment: ) спасибо! Голова не соображает. Долго думал над тем как подгружать данные из json